# Spacemacs launches normal emacs

Tags: spacemacs

I have used spacemacs in the past however it isn't working with my current installation and setup. Instead when I launch emacs it seems that the normal emacs is being launched with the white background and button menu.

This is my setup.

I downloaded emacs on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
I cloned spacemacs as per instructions, after the emacs install.
I ssh to my Ubuntu station and forward the X11

Is there something about this setup that explains why spacemacs as I recall it , black and no button menu doesn't launch, but instead the normal emacs launches.

[image]

Comment: make sure you clone spacemacs into `~/.emacs.d` and there is not a `~/.emacs`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I copied the git clone command and pasted it. I have double checked and it is ~/.emacs.d

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I discovered that I also had a .emacs file in my home directory. I removed it and now works fine

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you elaborate on your answer?